# Can anybody explain the time complexity of this code?

Tags: time-complexity

[Explain time complexity of the code given in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbDV9.jpg)

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of code. Type the code into your question.

Comment: The inner for loop has a cost of O(log n) because the number of times j needs to be doubled to reach n is log n.  This inner loop is executed about n/2 times because is is assigned about n/2 (plus 1) different values.  Thus, the total cost is (n/2)* log n = O(n log n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have two loops, the top one is quite simple, but the second one is a tad bit more tricky.

```
for (i = n/2; i < n; i) // ~n/2 so O(n)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j = 2 * j) // How many times does this run for n
```

So `j` doubles after every iteration until we reach `n`, so if we double `n`, `j` will only do one extra iteration! Alternatively, you could say that `log_2 n` is how many times we can double `j` to reach `n`.

So the time complexity is `O(n log n)`.